# Installing 'papertrail/remote_syslog2' manually, not found executable file

Tags: php, laravel, papertrail-app

I am trying to setup papertrail logging for my laravel app on my virtual machine (GCP - compute engine) having linux OS (Ubutu 18.04).
Following the steps as recommended by papertrail(using remote_syslog2), so downloading remote_syslog2: https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/releases/tag/v0.20

I have downloaded the package using.
`wget -c https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/archive/v0.20.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz`

As after extracting it goes to `remote_syslog2-0.20` directory, so i move it to mentioned folder.
`mv remote_syslog2-0.20 remote_syslog`

To follow : https://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-text-log-files-in-unix#manual

now it couldn't found any file with name `./remote_syslog`.

Then also followed the steps from: https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2#installing
but not succeed with :
`sudo cp ./remote_syslog /usr/local/bin`

Please help me with correct steps, or let me know if i am doing anything wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using wrong file path to download:

```
wget -c https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/archive/v0.20.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz
```

Download with correct file path resolve the issue :

```
wget -c https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/releases/download/v0.20/remote_syslog_linux_amd64.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz
```